# pyenv installation of python 2.7.8 failed on MACOS

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I try to install python 2.7.8 for a project that use this python version.

But when I use the command :

```
$ pyenv install 2.7.8
```

I have this error message :

```
python-build: use openssl from homebrew 
python-build: use readline from homebrew 
Downloading Python-2.7.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tar.xz 
Installing Python-2.7.8... 
patching file ./Lib/site.py 
patching file ./Lib/ssl.py 
patching file ./Modules/_ssl.c 
python-build: use readline from homebrew ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
        
Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem. 
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems
        
BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.6 using python-build 20180424)
        
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/xj/fd4h39yj5tn126v2rpf729km0000gn/T/python-build.20200719233445.90241 Results logged to /var/folders/xj/fd4h39yj5tn126v2rpf729km0000gn/T/python-build.20200719233445.90241.log
        
Last 10 log lines: 
(cd /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/bin; ln -s python2-config python-config) 
test -d /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/pkgconfig || /usr/bin/install -c -d -m 755 /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/pkgconfig
rm -f /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/pkgconfig/python2.pc 
(cd /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/pkgconfig; ln -s python-2.7.pc python2.pc) 
rm -f /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/pkgconfig/python.pc 
(cd /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/pkgconfig; ln -s python2.pc python.pc) 
rm -f /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/share/man/man1/python2.1 
(cd /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/share/man/man1; ln -s python2.7.1 python2.1) 
rm -f /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/share/man/man1/python.1 
(cd /Users/nekcorp/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/share/man/man1; ln -s python2.1 python.1)
```

I have see the link in the description and I have export the CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS environment variable, but I still have the error message.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://superuser.com/a/1440224

Comment: Yes I did but no change.

Comment: macs come with python version 2.7 I Think.  I know the come with Python 2 and I think its version 2.7. Could be version 2.8.

Comment: @jmh My problem concern all versions of Python under version 2.7.13. I can install Python 2.7.13, 2.7.14, but not Python 2.7.12, 2.7.11 ...... 2.7.7 is the last version I have test.

Comment: @mnekkach, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Same issue. Tried multiple fixes but to no avail. @mnekkach, could you find a fix?